# HTTP Status 500 servlet java + mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I have used Mysql connection in my java servlet. Mysql connector driver was installed in Intellij Idea, db "new_schema", table "users" were created. I added 1 note there. So i want to print fields of this note in web-brouser. htto status 500 error was appeared.

---

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
    DBconnect.getData(DBconnect.java:34)
    mainClass.doGet(mainClass.java:25)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.15 logs.

________
```

Help me plz!

MainClass

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;


    /**
     * Created by Yuriy on 01.01.2015.
     */
    @WebServlet(name = "mainClass")
    public class mainClass extends HttpServlet {


        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        }

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            DBconnect db = new DBconnect();
            PrintWriter y = response.getWriter();
                db.getData();
                y.println(db.name);
                y.println(db.age);
            y.close();

        }
    }
```

DBconnect class

```
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 * Created by Yuriy on 02.01.2015.
 */
public class DBconnect  implements Serializable{
    private Connection con;
    private Statement st;
    private ResultSet res;
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public DBconnect(){

            try{
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/new_schema","shipovalovyuriy","12321098");
                st = con.createStatement();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.err.println ("Cannot connect to database server");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

    }


    public void getData(){
        String query = "select * from users";
        try {
            res = st.executeQuery(query);
            setName(res.getString("name"));
            setAge(res.getInt("age"));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.getErrorCode();
        }
    }
    public void setName(String x){
        name = x;
    }
    public void setAge(int y){
        age = y;
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>

        <servlet-name>FirstSevlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>mainClass</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FirstSevlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Do you see any other exception? which is line 34 in source? do you see "Cannot connect to database server" somewhere in standard error log?

Comment: this usage of `ResultSet` is odd. I think you forgot to call `next()`

Comment: Cannot connect to database server
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1295)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1147)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
 at DBconnect.<init>(DBconnect.java:20)
 at mainClass.doGet(mainClass.java:23)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpSer....

Comment: @almasshaikh 
 
Cannot connect to database server

Comment: Thats the issue! is your mysql driver jar in your classpath?

Comment: @almasshaikh Yes it is in External Libraries Path in my project

Comment: are you using eclipse or running it from commandline?

Comment: @almasshaikh i am using Intellij IDea 14

Answer (score 0):

You need copy Mysql driver connector .jar file to Tomcat /lib directory